# Read csv file and split in columns keeping column names. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When i import csv file with ";" separator and then split columns, they appear without original names but indexed.

How to keep names when splitting columns? 
I do it with the following code: (the test file can be found [here](https://github.com/veronique-ka/tests/blob/master/test.csv)

```
data= pd.read_csv('path')
data=data.iloc[:,0]
data = data.str.split(';', expand=True)
```

i just simply rename them but I wonder if it's possible to keep them as they are. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split` for original columns:

```
data= pd.read_csv('path')
df = data.iloc[:,0].str.split(';', expand=True)
df.columns = data.columns[0].split('; ')
print (df)
   code units price
0  4017   142    20
1   808    76    15
2   316    39     7
3   209    27    45
4   344    14    32
```

Or use `sep=';'`, but also is necessary `quoting=3` and then remove `"` form first and last column name and with first and last column values by `strip`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('path', sep=";", quoting=3)
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip('" ')
data.iloc[:, [0, -1]] = data.iloc[:, [0, -1]].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael! I was really puzzled with this task and the solution is very simple :) I just didn't not understand why "str.split" doesn't split columns names together with data. The first option is more clear to me :)

Comment: @Vero - Yes, also if necessary last step should be `df = df.astype(int)`